# Cannot create basic_vectorstream<std::vector<char>> in Boost 1.55+

Tags: boost

Moving from Boost 1.54 to 1.55 I now get this error during compilation (VS2010):

```
void GzipDecompression::Decompress(const unsigned char * src, int length)
{
  if(src)
  {
      // Create an input-stream source for the data buffer so we can used the boost filtering buffer
      std::ifstream inputstream;
      typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> Device;
      boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<Device> buffer((char *)src, length);

      // Inflate using the GZIP filter
      filtering_streambuf<input> in;
      in.push(gzip_decompressor());
      in.push(buffer);

      // Get the result into a vector
      boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<char>> vectorStream;
      copy(in, vectorStream);
      std::vector<char> output(vectorStream.vector()); 
  }
}

error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<CharVector> *' to 'volatile const std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *' exists, but is inaccessible    c:\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp    57  1
```

It appears this is now failing:

```
boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<char>> vectorStream;
```

What has changed so this doesn't compile?

Update After Reply: I've tried changing the output to this:

```
  std::istream instream(&in);

  typedef std::istream_iterator<char> istream_iterator;
  typedef std::ostream_iterator<char> ostream_iterator;

  std::vector<char> output;
  std::copy(istream_iterator(instream), istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(output));
```

But the output is different.  Do I have to flush the stream or something?

Update2:  Apparently the istream_iterator strips CR LF etc. Here is my working function

```
void GzipDecompression::Decompress(const unsigned char * src, int length)
{
  if(src)
  {
      // Create an input-stream source for the data buffer so we can used the boost filtering buffer
      std::ifstream inputstream;
      typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> Device;
      boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<Device> buffer((char *)src, length);

      // Inflate using the GZIP filter
      filtering_streambuf<input> in;
      in.push(gzip_decompressor());
      in.push(buffer);

      // Get the result into a vector
      std::istream instream(&in);

      typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> istreambuf_iterator;


      std::vector<char> output;
      std::copy(istreambuf_iterator(instream), istreambuf_iterator(), std::back_inserter(output));

  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the error doesn't emerge from the line you mention. Instead, it's generated deep in the template instantiations for `copy_impl`. The problem seems to be that Boost Iostreams tries to be smart about detecting when people use "raw buffers" as devices/streams.

The problem with that is that the Interprocess stream implementation (privately) inherits its buffer class and as such, this confuses the detection because a conversion to base seems to be available but not accessible.

This can be reproduced in GCC as well as VS2013 update 4 and all using Boost 1_58_0 as well. As such it is an error that can be reported to the Boost developers. I'd suggest it is a weakness in the Boost Interprocess implementation, although Boost Iostreams devs might be interested in making their overload selection more robust in the presence of private base classes...

In the mean time, consider using a simple `boost::iostreams::array_sink` or `boost::iostreams::back_insert_device` (IIRC) which is pretty much guaranteed to play well with Boost Iostreams, and achieves the same goals.

Comment: Thanks. I worked out the copy line was the issue after posting.  I've included my attempt at reading an alternative method but it provides a different output than originally.  Would appreciate any insight.  Thanks